# Как сделать толковый кэш на php?

Tags: php, memcached, кэширование

Сайт - лента вопросов и ответов к ним

Примерно как тут

Пихать массивы по файлам научился, достаю из базы массив, потом серелизую и пихаю в файл

Способ работает на ура

Хотелось бы услышать что нибудь толковое про `memcache+apc`

Как это вообще использовать

не могу же я все запихнуть в оперативку как на жесткий диск

Если есть простенькие примеры для легкого старта, буду благодарен

Вообще не врубаюсь в эту тему

Answer (score 1):

Толковый кеш, это когда ты знаешь узкое место и пытаешься его устранить.

Найди что у тебя тормозит прежде чем что то кешировать. Вероятно вопрос решится нативным кешем твой БД

Answer (score -1):

> хотелось бы услышать что нибудь
> толковое про memcache+apc

Пригодно в случае если у Вас настраиваемый VPS or VDS. в [Google](https://www.google.com.ua/) чтива по запросу "[Ускорение PHP](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+PHP)" море!

**UPD:**

Вот свежая ссылка по теме: [DevConf 2013 14 июня — опубликована программа секции PHP, автор PHP расскажет про ускорение PHP в 6 раз](http://habrahabr.ru/company/devconf/blog/182148/)

Comment: вот именно это чтиво... по нему можно написать нечто кривенькое на подобии как оптимизировать цикл или как запихнуть по файлам используя ob_start

уже смотрел гугл много раз

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj тогда вероятней всего - Это вопрос на форум [РутКод](http://admin.hashcode.ru/). Так как вся магия делается на стороне сервера и скриптами тут не обойтись или скриптовыми решениями!

Comment: @dfhsfhgf, а что вы хотите слушать собственно? Если вы понимаете что такое memcache/apc и для чего они нужны, то я вообще не понимаю во что тут еще врубаться то?

По поводу примеров для легкого старта и того, что ничего толкового в сети нет, вы, мягко говоря, лукавите.

И главный вопрос - зачем вам все это нужно, если ваш способ работает на ура?

Comment: не могу понять зачем нужен apc запутался в нем

с memcache вроде разобрался, хорошая замена кэша на диске, но для чего нужен apc не понял

На конкретном примере если можно обьясните, хоть на словах
где именно apc выигрывает?

описание читал:

apc - это кеш для байт-кода php, чтоб интерпретатор не интерпретировал каждый раз заново, а выполнял уже интерпретированный код из кеша, работает как модуль для php. 

memcache - это хранилище ключ/значение в оперативной памяти, вешается на порт или unix-сокет.

не понятно в каком месте можно использовать apc...

Comment: мой способ работает на ура до поры до времени

до этого тоже все работало на ура без способа пока не стала отображаться белая страница с надписью мэни конектс

мне нужно это все понять, а потом понять как устроен yii в плане кэширования внутри (я еще не вникал в yii)

+доработать свои проекты

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj, удивляет Ваше высказывание

     не могу понять зачем нужен apc запутался в нем

Я тоже, до Вашего вопроса, просто не знал о такой штуке, поинтересовался 

гугл

    apc php

выдает массу материала. 

почитайте, например, [это](http://www.prolinux.org/node/137). IMHO все просто: ставите, перезапускаете, после чего интерпретатор PHP начинает кэшировать скрипты, используя вызовы функций из `apc.so`.

На практике, наверное, будет куча ньюансов, но принцип-то понятен.

Answer (score -1):

Зачем изобретать велосипед?.. все уже придумано для нас: [Redis](http://redis.io/)

Comment: redis шустрее простого чтения-записи в файлы?

Comment: редис работает с памятью и систематичсеки сбрасывает скриншот базы на диск, таким образом и производительность - высокая, и надежность - достаточная.

Answer (score -1):

Есть интересная библиотека https://github.com/mikecao/sparrow   там реализовано кеширование в memcahed и других. Легко использовать, да и код легко разобрать если нужен только пример работы.